# Print random lines respecting the order of the source file

Tags: shell, sed, awk, sort, random

I have a large text file (~500K lines) with short sentences (couple of words long). Additionally, there is some XML markup in most of the lines. Finally, the text file has been sorted *before* the markup has been added! Adding the XML markup changes the alphabetic sort but this is desired.

My question is: **How can I print random lines respecting the order of the source file?**

I know I could just use the shuf command and sort the result. The problem is that the markup will mess up the sort.

I could also write a `python` script which loads the text file in a list, generates some random numbers, sorts them and uses them as indices to pull out the lines. If possible, I would prefer standard *nix command-line tools.

Sample data:

```
<CITY>anaconda</CITY> city is in <STATE>montana</STATE>
let's go to <CITY>rome</CITY>
please find <CITY>berlin</CITY>
where is <CITY>cairo</CITY> in <COUNTRY>egypt</COUNTRY>
```

For example, it would be great if I could pull out the line 2 and 3. Lines 1,3 and 4 are also good. If I get the line 3, 1 and 4, this is not good.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this:

```
nl file | shuf -n2 | sort -n | cut -f2-
```

- `nl` to number the lines,
- `shuf` to shuffle and limit the output to 2 lines (`-n`),
- `sort` to rebuild the original order,
- and `cut` to remove the numeration of `nl`.

It will print 2 lines of your file in the original order of the file. Use `shuf -n X`, where `X` can be any number.

Comment: I love this solution!

Answer (score 7):

The selection of a random line from a file without sorting (or even knowing how many lines there are!) is covered in "The Art of Computer Programming", Volume 2, Section 3.4.2 by Donald E. Knuth. This is trivial to implement, e.g.:

```
(echo foo; echo bar; echo zot) \
| perl -nle 'rand $. < 1 && ( $line = $_ ); END { print $line }'
```

Or try `shuf`, which allows the selection of a certain number of lines, though may thus require more memory than the select-one Knuth algo.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it with a while loop and $RANDOM like:

```
while read line; do
    if ((RANDOM%2)); then
        echo $line;
    fi;
done < _path_
```

which will print about half the lines, which you could control with the condition in the `if`